# Why does type annotation for Int as Double work but not Double as Int?

Tags: swift

In Swift, a type annotation works to make an integer a double

```
  let num: Double = 100
  print(num)
```

Why does a type annotation not do the same for a double to integer (error of cannot convert value of type 'Double' to specified type 'Int')?

```
  let num: Int = 100.0
  print(num)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Converting an `Int` literal to a `Double` works solely because `Double` conforms to [`ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyintegerliteral):

> The standard library integer and floating-point types, such as Int and Double, conform to the ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral protocol. You can initialize a variable or constant of any of these types by assigning an integer literal.

For the second code to work, `Int` would have to conform to `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`.

```
extension Int : ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {
    public typealias FloatLiteralType = Double

    public init(floatLiteral value: Int.FloatLiteralType) {
        self.init(value)
    }
}

let a: Int = 100.0 // works
```

I don't particularly recommend doing this though. This might cause you to accidentally pass a double value to a function expecting an `Int`, without the compiler complaining.